# Is it correct this construction with the expression "have something in mind"?

Tags: grammar, expressions, word-usage, construction

I have a doubt related to the expression "to have something in mind". Is it correct to add information between the beginning and the end of it?

For example, like this:
"I have so many things I want to do in mind".

Answer (score 1):

A well-written advertisement from [Ritten House Inn, Wisconsin](https://www.rittenhouseinn.com/blog/top-10-things-to-do-in-bayfield-this-summer-part-two) contains:

> - *As you plan your trip to northern Wisconsin on the shores of Lake Superior, keep these top 10 Things to Do in mind.*

However, 'things to do' is a fixed phrase punchier and more compact than 'so many things I want to do'.

> - *Always have something fun to do in mind.*
> - *Self-visualization helps you keep what you're trying to accomplish in mind.*
> - *Have a clear map of the one thing you'd like to accomplish in mind.*

(from many examples found on the internet) are unremarkable, though perhaps the last is getting clunky.

Acceptability hinges not on grammaticality so much as idiomaticity here; how much material is inserted, and how complex it is grammatically, are the deciding factors.

- *'I have so many things I want to do before the first winter storms blow in from the north and make travelling nigh on impossible in mind.'*

has become unacceptably unwieldy.